# Angular WebRTC error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription'

Tags: angular, firebase, webrtc

so I have been trying to make a peer-to-peer video-call service using webRTC and I have come across this error and don't really know how to solve it. I don't have that much experience with webRTC so I just adapted a project I found online to my requirements and also the documentation is not up-to-date so it is hard to find information on it.

This is the full error and I have attached below the code.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable
> Error: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable

Code:

```
<div id="buttons">
  <button
    class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised"
    [disabled]="!isDisabled"
    id="cameraBtn"
    (click)="openUserMedia($event)"
  >
    <i class="material-icons mdc-button__icon" aria-hidden="true"
      >perm_camera_mic</i
    >
    <span class="mdc-button__label">Open camera & microphone</span>
  </button>
  <button
    class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised"
    [disabled]="isDisabled"
    id="createBtn"
    (click)="createRoom()"
  >
    <i class="material-icons mdc-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">group_add</i>
    <span class="mdc-button__label">Create room</span>
  </button>
  <button
    class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised"
    [disabled]
    id="joinBtn"
    (click)="joinRoomById(roomId.value)"
    [disabled]="isDisabled"
  >
    <i class="material-icons mdc-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">group</i>
    <span class="mdc-button__label">Join room</span>
  </button>
  <button
    class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised"
    disabled="!isDisabled"
    id="hangupBtn"
    (click)="hangUp($event)"
  >
    <i class="material-icons mdc-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">close</i>
    <span class="mdc-button__label">Hangup</span>
  </button>
</div>
<div>
  <span id="currentRoom"></span>
</div>
<div id="videos">
  <video
    id="localVideo"
    [muted]="'muted'"
    autoplay
    [srcObject]="localStream"
    playsinline
  ></video>
  <video
    id="remoteVideo"
    autoplay
    playsinline
    [srcObject]="remoteStream"
  ></video>
</div>
<div
  class="mdc-dialog"
  id="room-dialog"
  role="alertdialog"
  aria-modal="true"
  aria-labelledby="my-dialog-title"
  aria-describedby="my-dialog-content"
>
  <div class="mdc-dialog__container">
    <div class="mdc-dialog__surface">
      <h2 class="mdc-dialog__title" id="my-dialog-title">Join room</h2>
      <div class="mdc-dialog__content" id="my-dialog-content">
        Enter ID for room to join:
        <div class="mdc-text-field">
          <input
            type="text"
            id="roomId"
            #roomId
            class="mdc-text-field__input"
            name="roomId"
          />
          <label class="mdc-floating-label" for="my-text-field">Room ID</label>
          <div class="mdc-line-ripple"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="mdc-dialog__actions">
        <button
          type="button"
          class="mdc-button mdc-dialog__button"
          data-mdc-dialog-action="no"
        >
          <span class="mdc-button__label">Cancel</span>
        </button>
        <button
          id="confirmJoinBtn"
          type="button"
          class="mdc-button mdc-dialog__button"
          data-mdc-dialog-action="yes"
          (click)="confirm(roomId?.value)"
        >
          <span class="mdc-button__label">Join</span>
        </button>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mdc-dialog__scrim"></div>
</div>
```

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {
  addDoc,
  collection,
  doc,
  Firestore,
  getDoc,
  getDocs,
  onSnapshot,
  setDoc,
  updateDoc,
} from 'firebase/firestore';
import Peer from 'peerjs';
import { CallService } from '../call.service';
import { SignalingService } from '../signaling.service';
import AngularFirestore from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-video-call',
  templateUrl: './video-call.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video-call.component.css'],
})
export class VideoCallComponent implements OnInit {
  db = getFirestore();
  peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();
  configuration = {
    iceServers: [
      {
        urls: [
          'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302',
          'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302',
        ],
      },
    ],
    iceCandidatePoolSize: 10,
  };
  isDisabled = false;

  localStream: MediaStream = new MediaStream();
  remoteStream: MediaStream = new MediaStream();

  roomId: any;
  btn = document.getElementById('createBtn');

  constructor(
    private dialogReference: MatDialogRef<VideoCallComponent>,

    private location: Location,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: { doctor: string; user: string },
    private signalingService: SignalingService,
    private callService: CallService
  ) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  async openUserMedia(e: any) {
    this.localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      video: true,
      audio: true,
    });
    this.remoteStream = new MediaStream();
  }
  async joinRoomById(roomId: any) {
    console.log(roomId);
    if (roomId) {
      const roomRef = doc(collection(this.db, 'rooms'), roomId);
      const roomSnapshot = await getDoc(roomRef);
      console.log('Got room:', roomSnapshot.exists);

      if (roomSnapshot.exists()) {
        console.log(
          'Create PeerConnection with configuration: ',
          this.configuration
        );
        this.peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(this.configuration);
        this.registerPeerConnectionListeners();
        this.localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
          this.peerConnection.addTrack(track, this.localStream);
        });

        // Code for collecting ICE candidates below

        // Code for collecting ICE candidates above

        this.peerConnection.addEventListener('track', (event) => {
          console.log('Got remote track:', event.streams[0]);
          event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach((track) => {
            console.log('Add a track to the remoteStream:', track);
            this.remoteStream.addTrack(track);
          });
        });
      }
      console.log(roomSnapshot.data());
      const offer = roomSnapshot.data()['offer'];
      console.log('Got offer:', offer);
      await this.peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(
        new RTCSessionDescription(offer)
      );
      const answer = await this.peerConnection.createAnswer();
      console.log('Created answer:', answer);
      await this.peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);

      const roomWithAnswer = {
        answer: {
          type: answer.type,
          sdp: answer.sdp,
        },
      };

      await updateDoc(roomRef, roomWithAnswer);
      // Code for creating SDP answer above
      const queryCalleeSnapShot = collection(roomRef, 'calleeCandidates');
      const uns = onSnapshot(queryCalleeSnapShot, (snapshot: any) => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach(async (change: any) => {
          if (change.type === 'added') {
            let data = change.doc.data();
            console.log(
              `Got new remote ICE candidate: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`
            );
            await this.peerConnection.addIceCandidate(
              new RTCIceCandidate(data)
            );
          }
        });
      });
      // Listening for remote ICE candidates below
    }
  }
  async confirm(roomId: string) {
    console.log(roomId);
    await this.joinRoomById(roomId);
  }
  async createRoom() {
    this.isDisabled = true;
    const roomRef = await doc(collection(this.db, 'rooms'));
    console.log(
      'Create PeerConnection with configuration: ',
      this.configuration
    );
    this.peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(this.configuration);

    this.registerPeerConnectionListeners();

    this.localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
      this.peerConnection.addTrack(track, this.localStream);
    });
    const callerCandidatesCollection = collection(roomRef, 'callerCandidates');
    this.peerConnection.addEventListener('icecandidate', (event) => {
      if (!event.candidate) {
        console.log('Got final candidate!');
        return;
      }

      console.log('Got candidate: ', event.candidate);
      addDoc(callerCandidatesCollection, event.candidate.toJSON);
    });
    const offer = await this.peerConnection.createOffer();
    await this.peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
    console.log('Created offer:', offer);

    const roomWithOffer = {
      offer: {
        type: offer.type,
        sdp: offer.sdp,
      },
    };
    setDoc(roomRef, roomWithOffer);
    this.roomId = roomRef.id;
    console.log(`New room created with SDP offer. Room ID: ${roomRef.id}`);
    this.peerConnection.addEventListener('track', (event) => {
      console.log('Got remote track:', event.streams[0]);
      event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach((track) => {
        console.log('Add a track to the remoteStream:', track);
        this.remoteStream.addTrack(track);
      });
    });
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(this.db, 'rooms'));
    querySnapshot.forEach(async (snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.data();
      if (
        !this.peerConnection.currentRemoteDescription &&
        data &&
        data['answer']
      ) {
        console.log('Got remote description: ', data['answer']);
        const rtcSessionDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(data['answer']);
        console.log(rtcSessionDescription);
        await this.peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(rtcSessionDescription);
      }
    });
    const queryCalleeSnapShot = collection(roomRef, 'calleeCandidates');
    const uns = onSnapshot(queryCalleeSnapShot, (snapshot: any) => {
      snapshot.docChanges().forEach(async (change: any) => {
        if (change.type === 'added') {
          let data = change.doc.data();
          console.log(`Got new remote ICE candidate: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
          await this.peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data));
        }
      });
    });
  }
  async hangUp(e: any) {
    this.localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
      track.stop();
    });
    if (this.remoteStream) {
      this.remoteStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
    }

    if (this.peerConnection) {
      this.peerConnection.close();
    }
    this.localStream = new MediaStream();
    this.remoteStream = new MediaStream();
    document.location.reload();
  }

  registerPeerConnectionListeners() {
    this.peerConnection.addEventListener('icegatheringstatechange', () => {
      console.log(
        `ICE gathering state changed: ${this.peerConnection.iceGatheringState}`
      );
    });

    this.peerConnection.addEventListener('connectionstatechange', () => {
      console.log(
        `Connection state change: ${this.peerConnection.connectionState}`
      );
    });

    this.peerConnection.addEventListener('signalingstatechange', () => {
      console.log(
        `Signaling state change: ${this.peerConnection.signalingState}`
      );
    });

    this.peerConnection.addEventListener('iceconnectionstatechange ', () => {
      console.log(
        `ICE connection state change: ${this.peerConnection.iceConnectionState}`
      );
    });
  }
}
```

```
body {
  background: #eceff1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#message {
  background: white;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 100px auto 16px;
  padding: 32px 24px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#message h2 {
  color: #ffa100;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 0 8px;
}

#message h1 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  margin: 0 0 16px;
}

#message p {
  line-height: 140%;
  margin: 16px 0 24px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#message a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background: #039be5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#message,
#message a {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

#load {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  body,
  #message {
    margin-top: 0;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  body {
    border-top: 16px solid #ffa100;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 1em;
}

button {
  margin: 0.2em 0.1em;
}

div#videos {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div#videos > video {
  background: black;
  width: 640px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

It looks like the webRTC documentation and Firebase are not yet up-to-date so I did not really try much since it took me years to find the actual replacements for all the operations used

Comment: The error comes from this line of code in createRoom function:                                                                               await this.peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(rtcSessionDescription);  Any advice is good I am going insane with this webRTC stuff